# Using PHP for thumb scanning device

Tags: php, mysql, biometrics

I am really excited about sharing my experience on Stack Overflow. I have a strong passion for technology. My stronger area is PHP, but now i got a small work in which i have to let the user log in using a Thumb Scanner device, not username and password. My website is hosted on a hosting site obviously.

I did some findings and i came to know of "Digital Persona 4500". I know PHP is a scripting language and i can not directly communicate with the thumb scanning device, thumb scanning devices have their SDK's.

So my question is:
How can i make it happen? i have two systems where two thumb scanning devices are placed. How can i make them interact with the server?

Comment: If you're on Windows you could use COM; otherwise you'd be looking at a PHP extension.

Comment: @Jack I'm guessing that the computer with the thumb scanner and the webserver are two different machines. OP, could you please clarify that?

Comment: You are aware that those thumb scanning devices offer an extremely low security? Even lower than simple plain passwords?

Comment: Yeah, you could cut the finger off and use it!

Comment: @YUNOWORK Oh no, it's way simpler than that .. take a high dpi picture of the fingerprint, then create a latex finger which you then use to bypass all security :D

Comment: my website is hosted on a linux machine

Comment: @Jack I wanted to be funny and laugh about arkaschas comment ... I feel so so so stupid now. :(

Comment: @arkascha How can i prove this? that biometric devices are less secure than user/pass system?

Comment: It is not a limitation of biometric devices in general, but of those typical cheap thumb scanning devices. All you need to get past them is a strip of tesa and some glue. Proven millions of times. The problem simply is that they cannot differ between a "living" tumb and something "thumblike".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not implement it using PHP. 
PHP is hosted in server while website is displayed in client side. Communication with thumb scanning device has to be done in client side.

As far as I know it can not be done using HTML5, so you are left with 3 options

1. Flash
2. Java
3. COM (Windows only

I am not sure about Flash and COM but you can definitely use JAVA to interact with thumb scanning device. It will send back the scanned information to server which can be used to validate user.

Note that validation is server side and can be written in PHP

Comment: Rahul, Do i need to write some code in java for those machines on which biometric/thumb scanning devices are installed?

Comment: @user3368239 Just like you embed a Flash into a website, you can similarly embed a java jar file to be downloaded and executed in client machine, it will surely ask for user permission but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in PHP right now, I am not sure about future enhancement in PHP ;)